# Логистическая регрессия в Python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

вот код с курса

```
y_pred_train=logreg.predict(x_train)
```

```
y_predict_train=logreg.predict_proba(x_train)[:,1]
```

```
logreg.score(x_test,y_train)
```

Вот хорошее объяснение,которое я нашел.

**model.predict(X_test) – предсказать значения целевой переменной**

**model.predict_proba() – выдать «степень уверенности» в ответе
(вероятность) – для некоторых моделей**

**model.score() – в большинстве моделей встроены методы оценки их
качества работы**

1)Не очень понимаю,что значит степень уверенности? и почему нельзя дать ответ,в котором уверенность 100%?

2)как score() оценивает работу модели,если на вход подаются x_train  и y_train?
Хотя по логике же должны y_pred и y_train?
И вообще что значит оценка работы?

Где-то говорится про определитель,хотя я не знаком с этим понятием.

**score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None)[source] Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction. ... A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0. From sklearn documentation**

3. и последнее, почему мы всё присваиваем разным переменным?

   Почему нельзя
   `a=predict(x_test)`
   `b=a.predict_proba()`

Я подозреваю,что нам это сошло с рук,из-за того что я определил заранее random_state, то есть сколько раз не вызывай predict(), коэффициенты или же веса будут одинаковые.
Но я не сильно  уверен в этом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предыдущем вашем вопросе вам посоветовали прочитать хотя-бы какую-нибудь литературу касательно темы, ну хоть для младших школьников. Похоже, вы к совету не прислушались. Потому как по вопросу видно, что никакого настоящего продвижения в понимании того, чем вы занимаетесь у вас как не было так и нет, ну разве что вы посмотрели форматы еще трех команд, так и не поняв, что они делают и вообще -  зачем это все.

Тем не менее попробую ответить

> 1)Не очень понимаю,что значит степень уверенности? и почему нельзя
> дать ответ,в котором уверенность 100%?

В методе, который вы как бы "изучаете", результат получается в виде некоторого числа в пределах от нуля до единицы. Для некоторых (многих) задачах - это именно то, что надо - показать, что возможны оба варианта и показать, какова вероятность того, что объект принадлежит одному классу или другому. Для других задач (их тоже много) надо дать абсолютно однозначный ответ, к какому классу принадлежит ответ. В этом случае ответ по первому варианту с помощью функции срабатывания приводится к двузначной логике "0"-"1".
При этом надо понимать, что ответ будет с ошибкой, которую надо бы еще и оценить. (см. ниже)

> 2)как score() оценивает работу модели,если на вход подаются x_train и
> y_train? Хотя по логике же должны y_pred и y_train? И вообще что
> значит оценка работы?

Именно x_train и y_train и должны подаваться на вход этой функции. Функция, зная, каким должен быть отклик модели y_train выполняет задачу классификации, а потом сравнивает полученный отклик с ожидаемым для каждого  x_train. Оценка означат показатель accuracy для (бинарной) классификации и значение коэффициента детерминации R^2 для моделей регрессии.

> и последнее, **почему мы всё присваиваем** разным переменным?
>
> Почему нельзя a=predict(x_test) b=a.predict_proba()

Что-то странное у вас написано. При этом вы просите нас рассказать вам, почему **вы** их так присваиваете?
По идее должно быть

```
а=model.predict(x_test)
а=model.predict_proba(x_test)
```

а хотите присваивать разным -  то

```
а=model.predict(x_test)
b=model.predict_proba(x_test)
```

Вообще-то ответы на все эти вопросы  можно найти прямо в документации:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

```
то есть сколько раз не вызывай predict(), коэффициенты или же веса будут одинаковые
```

А почему они должны быть разными, если вы используете одну и ту-же модель и одни и те-же данные?

Еще раз повторю - знание формата команд fit, predict или score  **НЕ** делает человека специалистом по машинному обучению.

Comment: Зачем читать документацию, если всегда можно спросить добрых людей )  Вообще печально, конечно, да

Comment: @CrazyElf я просто не всегда документацию понимаю, а так хорошо,когда за тебя все пережевывают. ШУТКА)) Вообще я еще поискал про score() и вроде догнал,как она работает –    if you use now the Xtrain to make predictions you will not get exactly Ytrain, but Ytrain', different somehow Ytrain' = logreg.predict(X_train)        

2) logreg.score(Xtrain,Ytrain) is calculating the difference between Ytrain and Ytrain' (an accuracy measure), but you did not need to explicitly calculate Y_train'. The library does this internally.

Comment: @Тима  -  А зачем тут растолковывать на английском то, что вам и так уже рассказали на русском?  Впрочем, мы очень рады, что вы кого-то там "догнали", но  будем очень все-таки надеяться, что вы наконец-то поняли, что надо не только   синтаксис методов учить.

Comment: Не могу догнать. Сначала говорите-знание формата команд fit, predict или score НЕ делает человека специалистом по машинному обучению. А потом- что надо не только синтаксис методов учить . Тем более я этого не отрицал)

Comment: Я говорил не так. Я говорил, что изучение должно идти от понимания того, какую задачу надо решить и как ее можно решить, к изучению того, каким средствами (в данном случае -  функциями, методами) результат достигается.  Это характерно для любого - по крайней мере технического или научного - знания и путей его получения.  В данном случае надо понимать, что делает изучаемый метод, а уж потом смотреть, какие параметры функции и методов. Вы же четко идете обратным путем.  Поэтому и появляется куча вопросов совершенно синтаксических при непонимании семантики процесса.